# ROS Answers SE migration: Why use ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My organization is not currently using ROS but I am intrigued. I've proposed the idea of us using ROS and the pragmatists inevitably ask, "what's the value of switching to ROS?"

I have some thoughts/ideas on this but am not yet skilled in ROS. So, I thought I'd throw the question out to you the experts,

Why is ROS so great?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61939/why-use-ros?/) by [joehays](https://answers.ros.org/users/3454/joehays/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-04**:
'What is ROS' and 'Why use ROS' etc have been answered here and also at the ros wiki. Since ROS has been around for more than 4 years now, these questions should not be encouraged, rather one should be asked to look up the wiki etc.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-05-06**:
I actually don't remember a wiki page answering this question (why use ROS), could someone comment and provide the link so that it can be captured with the question so that the information could point to the wiki?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-06**:
@trinighost Hello, (1) this is for 'What is ROS' ==> http://answers.ros.org/question/12230/what-is-ros-exactly-middleware-framework-operating-system/ and though the answer to (2) 'Why use ROS' is not so explicit, but you can find it here ==> http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy (for Groovy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- modular, nodes can be started separate from each other. This makes the development of a big robot system with multiple people much easier.
- good hardware support, ROS supports lots of sensors, actuators and whole robot platforms
- lots of algorithms already implemented and available as package
- good integration with other robot middlewares
- easy to use tools for development
- big community
- active development

But what the real value for your organisation is depends on the type of application.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-05-03**:\

- Communication setup is abstracted away.
- Pre-defined message types make debugging and visualization easy.
- Subscriber/publisher model is agnostic to where the data is coming from and how. You know there will be a specific type of data published on a specific topic, so you can easily listen in.